# JSP comparing hashmap key with an object value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am new to JSP and I am facing issue in executing a comparison of hashmap key and an object value. I have an object (Box) which has a string field (size). I have a hashmap also which contains list of Boxes based on size

```
Map<String, List<Box> boxCatgMap=new HashMap<String, List<Box>>();

  <s:iterator value="boxCatgMap" var="boxCatg">
        <s:set var="boxCatgKey" value="#boxCatg.key"/>
        <s:iterator value="boxes" var="box" status="ind">
           <s:if test="%{#box.size.equals(boxCatgKey)}">
            //some code
           </s:if></s:iterator>
  </s:iterator>
```

The if condition has some issue because of which it is not getting executed. Can any one please help what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: please try with # in front of boxCatgKey `test="%{#box.size.equals(#boxCatgKey)}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hash (#) in front of `boxCatgKey` too.

```
<s:if test="%{#box.size.equals(#boxCatgKey)}"></s:if>
```

When you use `Struts 2 data-tags` with the default scope (i.e action scope) :

```
<s:set var="boxCatgKey" value="#boxCatg.key"/>
```

You can access it by `#boxCatgKey`.